# Join lists with overlap

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a function that finds the area of overlap between two lists and returns the result of joining the two lists together. The overlap area is the longest suffix of the first list that matches a prefix of the second list and it only appears once in the resulting sequence.

```
> (list-overlap '(a a a t t t t) '(t t t t g g g g g))
(list 'a 'a 'a 't 't 't 't 'g 'g 'g 'g 'g)
> (list-overlap '(a a a) '(g g g))
(list 'a 'a 'a 'g 'g 'g)
> (list-overlap '(a t t a) '(t t a a))
(list 'a 't 't 'a 'a)
```

I created a function to check for a complete overlap, but I don't know how to just search for a partial and then complete the problem. Here is what I have for the prefix part:

```
(define (list-prefix? lst1 lst2)
  (or (null? lst1)
      (and (not (null? lst2))
           (equal? (first lst1 ) (first lst2))
           (list-prefix? (rest lst1 ) (rest lst2)))))
```

I was thinking you would use `(reverse ...)` and check each element one by one but then I have no way of removing the rest of the elements once I get to the final one, since there is not substring function for lists.

Any help would be great. And in ISL.

Comment: What are `ls` and `rs` in your `list-prefix?` function?

Comment: What do you mean by "check for a complete overlap"?

Comment: I didn't fully change the variable names, I was trying to make it easier to read. When I said overlap I meant that if the first list was '(1 2 3 4) and the second list was '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) then the first list would be a prefix and overlap with the second one.

Comment: It looks like you're editing your question to incorporate @Saposhiente 's answer? That's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
#lang htdp/isl
(define (list-prefix? lhs rhs)
  (or (empty? lhs)
      (and (not (empty? rhs))
           (eqv? (first lhs) (first rhs))
           (list-prefix? (rest lhs) (rest rhs)))))

(define (list-overlap lhs rhs)
  (if (list-prefix? lhs rhs)
      rhs
      (cons (first lhs) (list-overlap (rest lhs) rhs))))
```

Note that `list-prefix?` returns true if `lhs` is empty, so it is an adequate base case.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list-prefix?` function appears correct except that it is unnecessary to check for `(pair? lst2)`: this excludes the possibility that the two lists are the same list. You instead want `(not (null? lst2))`.

To determine what the overlap region is, you then simply iterate through `lst1` and check whether the list after each position is a prefix of `lst2`, and return the first such sublist.